# Working with Numpy arrays, getting an Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to code functions, that compute [financial greeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)) for B-S model.
I started with something like this:

```
def greeks_vanilla(S, K, r, q, t, T, sigma):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import norm

    tau = np.linspace(t, T, num = T)
    d1 = ( np.log(S/K) + (r - q + sigma**2 /2)*tau ) / (sigma * np.sqrt(tau))
    d2 = d1 - sigma*np.sqrt(tau)

    delta_call = np.exp(-q*tau) * norm.cdf(d1)
    delta_put = -np.exp(-q*tau) * norm.cdf(-d1)
    ...

    return {'d1':d1, 'd2': d2, 'delta_call': delta_call, 'delta_put': delta_put, ...}
```

'...' means, there are more greeks being computed, but it's not important here.
It was working fine, I had reasonable values, nice plots, etc.; however, my teacher told me, that he want to see those values versus not only time (tau on x-axis), but also versus S (S - stock price, on x-axis). In other words, I have to compute greeks for both tau and S changing.

I've tried following:

```
def greeks_vanilla(S, K, r, q, t, T, sigma):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import norm

    S = np.linspace(1, S, num = S)

    tau = np.linspace(t, T, num = T)
    d1 = ( np.log(S/K) + (r - q + sigma**2 /2)*tau ) / (sigma * np.sqrt(tau))
    d2 = d1 - sigma*np.sqrt(tau)

    delta_call = np.exp(-q*tau) * norm.cdf(d1)
    delta_put = -np.exp(-q*tau) * norm.cdf(-d1)
    ...
```

For both versions I initialized following params and run (a-variable):

```
S = 30.0 #Stock price
K = 50.0 #Strike price
r = 0.05 #Risk-free rate
q = 0.01 #also called delta, annual dividend yield
t = 1.0
T = 100.0
sigma = 0.15
a = greeks_vanilla(S, K, r, q, t, T, sigma)
```

It works fine in the first case, but when I want to vary S (second function), I'm getting following error:

```
     File "greeks.py", line 11, in greeks_vanilla
    d1 = ( np.log(S/K) + (r - q + sigma**2 /2)*tau ) / (sigma * np.sqrt(tau))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,) (100,)
```

I googled a bit, and it's look like there is something with Numpy library and it's data types (arrays). I'm not very skilled or experienced programmer (still learning), so I wasn't able to figure it by myself.
It looks like it works now only with S == 100 (S = T), but that's not desirable solution.
I've tried:

```
S = list(S)
```

But it only outputs:

```
File "greeks.py", line 11, in greeks_vanilla
    d1 = ( np.log(S/K) + (r - q + sigma**2 /2)*tau ) / (sigma * np.sqrt(tau))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
```

Please, help me find working solution of this. I don't know if I should try to loop overs S (I tried and failed...), do some data type tricks, calculate it other way (how?) or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you got this working for the 1D case, evaluating your function at each value in a `np.linspace`.  Now you're trying to get it to work in 2D and are still using `np.linspace`.

Numpy wants to work on things element-wise.  So when you give it two `linspace`s that are different sizes, it doesn't know how to map the elements from one `linspace` to elements in the other.  But if you think about what you want, you should realize that you want to evaluate your function at all pair combinations `(s, t)` where `s in S` and `t in tau`, and all those pairs are points on a 2D grid.  So the tool you want to be using is [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

Graphically, the way you've written it, you're trying to evaluate your expression only at the #s.

```
#...................
#...................
#...................
#...................
#...................
####################
```

and that's why numpy is complaining--it's saying I'm not sure which value in `tau` corresponds with what value of `S`.  What I'd like to do is either match one value of `tau` with all of `S` or pair them up, but that only happens with `len(tau)==len(S)` as you saw.  What you really want is to be evaluating your expression at all points on that grid, and that's what `np.meshgrid` will let you do.

Numpy's meshgrid can be tricky to understand how to use at first.  If you feed it two vectors (e.g. your `linspaces`), it will return two 2D arrays that specify the coordinates at every grid point spanned by those two vectors.  I imagine that you would probably like to do something like:

```
def greeks_vanilla(S, K, r, q, t, T, sigma):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import norm

    v1 = np.linspace(1, S, num = S)
    v2 = np.linspace(t, T, num = T)

    S, TAU = np.meshgrid(v1, v2)

    d1 = ( np.log(S/K) + (r - q + sigma**2 /2)*TAU ) / (sigma * np.sqrt(TAU))
    d2 = d1 - sigma*np.sqrt(TAU)

    delta_call = np.exp(-q*TAU) * norm.cdf(d1)
    delta_put = -np.exp(-q*TAU) * norm.cdf(-d1)
    ...
```

which doesn't raise the error anymore.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I had to do some work with getting those meshgrid values into my plots, but after some search it works fine!